# Python - Adding "hidden" values to tuples

Tags: python

I have a set of tuples, with each tuple having three data values. The problem I'm working on requires me to encode four data values in each tuple, but the fourth value shouldn't get factored in when determining tuple equivalence. More formally,

```
tuple1 = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
tuple2 = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')

tuple1 == tuple2  # Should be true
```

Additionally, if `tuple1` was in a set, `tuple2` cannot be added to that set

What's the best way to implement this "hidden" value such that tuple equivalence isn't affected by it?

I've considered creating a class that encloses a tuple, and override the equal() and hash() functions, so that the last element is irrelevant in that aspect. However, the problem I'm working on is computationally intensive, and so I was wondering if there are faster ways of implementing this functionality.

If you know of any, please share. Thank you.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality as far as I am aware.

Comment: Given your requirement to place items in sets I think you will have to write your own class. I'm also curious to see if there's other ways in which this can be done.

Comment: I need this equivalence functionality built into the data type, otherwise I can't use it with sets and hash tables.

Comment: Why don't you use a pandas dataframe?

Comment: You could try subclassing ``tuple``, with your extra value going into an instance slot rather than the tuple itself.

Comment: @jasonharper if memory efficiency is an issue, this might become problematic.

Comment: @jasonharper I was cooking up a solution when you mentioned it.

Comment: What do you want to be the output of `{tuple1} | {tuple2}`? Should it raise error, and if not, which tuple "wins"?

Comment: @wim Hmm, I'm not sure. I don't intend on using them in that manner. All I really care about is that they have the same hash value.

Comment: Well, if you are putting them inside dicts you still have to address that issue!  (sets are just dicts with null values)

Comment: Alright, I re-examined the problem structure. The output could be either sets. If "win" is based on which fourth value is bigger, `{tuple2}` should output. If "win" is based on which is smaller, output should be `{tuple1}`. Either heuristic is fine, as long as the choice is consistent (so can't choose arbitrarily). For completeness, if any of the first three values is different, the tuples are effectively different, and so the output should be the set `{tuple1, tuple2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `tuple` and using a combination of `__new__` and `__init__`, create a tuple that also holds the 4th attribute as a separate attribute. I don't know how "tuple-like" your solution needs to be, but this is a simple solution.

```
class MyTuple(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, a, b, c, d):
        return super(MyTuple, cls).__new__(cls, (a,b,c))

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.d = d

    @property
    def as_tuple(self):
        return self + (self.d,)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Mytuple' + repr(self.as_tuple)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.as_tuple)


tuple1 = MyTuple('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
tuple2 = MyTuple('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')

tuple3 = MyTuple('w', 'x', 'y', 'z')

my_dict = {tuple1:'one', tuple2:'two', tuple3:'three'}
print('hashed', my_dict)
```

Comment: I don't find the idea convincing.  Subclassing an immutable type into a mutable thing seems hairy.  Also we're now carrying around a `__dict__` on each instance... hmmm

Comment: Normally, putting ``__slots__ = ['d']`` in the class would avoid creating that dict on each instance - but unfortunately it doesn't work with tuples (due to their variable-size nature).

Comment: @wim - inheriting an immutable type isn't common perhaps but certainly has its uses and I don't find that part troubling. The extra space and extra time it takes to instantiate the object could be a deal breaker but on modern hardware it would have to be a significant data set before I'd worry. There are many ways python can burn your core and eat your RAM!

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, I was a bit surprised when `TypeError: nonempty __slots__ not supported for subtype of 'tuple'` showed up in my first attempt.

Comment: I'm not restricted to using tuples. As long as the data structure is hashable, all is good. The whole point is that I can use the tuple/MyTuple as a distinct key to a hash table. If tuple1 is a key in a dictionary, then Dict[tuple2] should return the same value as Dict[tuple1].

Comment: @Naldhelaan - I updated to show a `dict`. Three tuples go in, two come out because 2 shared a hash.

Comment: Subclasses of immutable types should generally also be immutable, otherwise the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is violated.  I think a custom class would be better here, subclassing tuple seems troublesome.

Comment: @wim - you are quite right that there are many potential pitfalls. What behavior should `(1,2,3) + MyTuple(4,5,6,7)` or `MyTuple(1,2,3,4)[2:]` have, come to mind. However, it is normal to use tuples as indexers so perahps we could just rename it to `MyIndex` and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of your problem as a set of tuples (each with a hidden value), couldn't you think of it as as dictionary mapping a given tuple to the hidden value?